# Manual position of background image in JfreeChart

Tags: margin, jfreechart, padding

It is possible to manually position the background image of a chart in JFreeChart?

At this moment is aligned on the bottom-right, but I want some margins (especially for the right margin):

```
chart.setBackgroundImage(image);
chart.setBackgroundImageAlignment(Align.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
```

Is not important that can be done with margins or paddings or empty border, I just want some 'free pixels'.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tricky solution:

We assume that I want to put a logo aligned to bottom-right with equal space margins (let's say 50px). To get that margin you can canvas the image in width and height by +50px for both directions (see photo 2). Don't forget to maintain transparent background (.png recommended).

[image]

[image]